# IONIC - Accordion menù with smooth animation

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, accordion

I've created an accordion side menù using this simple code:

**.html**

```
 <ion-content>
      <ion-item-group *ngFor="let tax of Wiki; let i=index"  (click)="toggleGroup(i)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i)}" >
        <ion-item-divider > {{tax[0]}}</ion-item-divider>
        <div *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
          <button text-wrap menuClose ion-item icon-left *ngFor="let p of tax[1]" (click)="goToPage(p.title.rendered, p.acf.nome, p.id, p.slug)">
            {{p.acf.nome}} 
          </button>
        </div>

      </ion-item-group>
  </ion-content>
```

**.ts**

```
toggleGroup(group) {
  if (this.isGroupShown(group)) {
     this.shownGroup = null;   
  } else {
      this.shownGroup = group;
  }
};

 isGroupShown(group) {
     return this.shownGroup === group;
    };
```

There is a way to add a smooth animation when I click **ion-item-group** and I open the accordion? 
I have no css applied to this code.

I've searched for a lot of accordion tutorial but none of them have a smooth animation applied.

Thank you.